# String validation with Regex - with a Do while loop

Tags: c#, regex, validation

Can I use a `do while` loop and regex to validate a string input, so that the string is rejected when a number is inside with `[:alpha:]`

```
Console.Write("Please Input The student First name/To cancel enter END> ");
StFName[count] = Console.ReadLine();
do
{
      Console.Write("Please Input The student First name/To cancel enter END> ");
      StFName[count] = Console.ReadLine();
} while (StFName =! "[:alpha:]");
```

This is my Dream scenario

Comment: Your question is not quite clear.

Comment: @LibertyLocked: It's similar to `[a-zA-Z]` in POSIX. [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do {
   Console.Write("Please Input The student First name/To cancel enter END> ");
   StFName[count] = Console.ReadLine();
} while (Regex.IsMatch(StfName[count], "\\d+"));
```

Any string with a numeric character will fail the validation.

Alternatively, if you want **non-alphanumeric** (*apart from whitespaces*) characters to also fail, you should use the following regex:

```
do {
   Console.Write("Please Input The student First name/To cancel enter END> ");
   StFName[count] = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!Regex.IsMatch(StfName[count], "[a-zA-Z\\s]+"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like:

```
Console.Write("Please Input The student First name/To cancel enter END> ");
StFName[count] = Console.ReadLine();
do
{
      Console.Write("Please Input The student First name/To cancel enter END> ");
      StFName[count] = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!Regex.IsMatch(StfName[count], "[[:alpha:]]"));
```